# Webpage on a loop - How to add a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, countdown

So I have an interactive touchscreen that I want to show off a website on a loop.

I've made the code to scroll from page to page on a 30 second delay. Now because it's a touch screen, I want people to be able to engage with it, so if they click on it, it opens up so they can manually scroll about (I can make arrows or whatever for that) but I want a countdown timer so it goes back to the loop if it's not touched within lets say 2 minutes.

Does anyone have a clue how to add a bit of code in for that? I'm not at all sure where to start

Thank you for any help.

Rich

Comment: it would be better if you have tried something..because SO is not the site where u will get readymade code in which u havnt tried anything before!

Comment: You could try having a click handler on the `document` element of the page, when clicked a timeout is cleared and reset to 2 minutes.

Comment: Ah sorry Neel, didn't know that - was wondering if there was a template out there. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Nunners - sounds like a plan. WIll give that a go. Many thanks chaps.

Comment: you can use clearTimeout to stop a timer, start another say "idle timer" and have an event that clears+starts again this timer each time an action is done on the page (use a global handler or something).